# Android game reverse http request body

Tags: android, http, protocol-buffers, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse requests that are made to an android game to learn more about how it works.

I was able to find endpoints requests that are made with frida and mitmproxy but now I'm stuck because the body of requests looks like encoded and I don't know what to do next.

Example of request I got with mitmproxy :

Request:

```
POST /v1/game/heartbeat HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Accept: application/x-protobuf
Sign: V6E0BcEySdvhWka8qqronw==
Timestamp: 1677850264960
Offset: 576384618343
Token: ***
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Version: 2.0.31.248
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.1; ONEPLUS A5000 Build/NMF26X)
Host: ****
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: AWSALB=*** AWSALBCORS=***
Content-Length: 76

WWVUPUYlVg5DfGkmJnUtGGcuUW5cfAABRGgiJSMocw1kegE9QnNcc0s2Vks+bidScXcSGx9mGw==
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 12
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 03 Mar 2023 13:31:05 GMT
Set-Cookie: AWSALB=***
Set-Cookie: AWSALBCORS=***
Token: ***
Sign: /n0stA/UOCtSC0BfFDjjvg==
X-Protobuf-Schema: GameLogicProto.proto
X-Protobuf-Message: api.HeartBeatResponse
requestId: 3c2b5566-f863-4390-af82-6aad9551eefb
Offset: 576384618343
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 ***.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: CDG52-P1
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
X-Amz-Cf-Id: LzO0HrZLu5BkCUfBFEjVfosNnkd2ViDHeFjgkf5Unq0buIoMnVTT_A==

S6q888yuVhkn
```

It looks like body of request are base64 encoded obviously but I can't do anything with decoded body. I think I have to do something with protobuf but I'm a bit lost here.

Someone know what I can do next ? Or a lead to follow ?

Thanks and have a nice day !

Update :

I've decompiled the apk and I've found all the code that I need to reverse all data BUT it's in .luac format encoded with a xxtea key or something.

Now I need to find a way to decrypt all luac file before decompiling them.

Is there a simple method to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is encoded using [Google Protocol Buffers](https://protobuf.dev/). The library definitely uses `X-Protobuf-*` headers so it can't be anything else.

I am not familiar with this library so I cannot offer a code example.

But the library which offers classes to decode messages can be found [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf). It's available in many different programming languages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Yep it seems that protobuf has done something here.

I've find protobuf file when decompiling the apk but files are in .luac format, I'm looking for a way to decompile lua now haha